# Installed plugins have status "Inactive"

Tags: impresspages

Impresspages v. 4.0.14.
All plugins whish i try to install and activate (FullTinyMCE-master, Favicon-master) have status inacative in left collumn and plugins don't work.

I install plugins by copying to server using ftp client. After click on **Activate** button. **Activate** button changes to **Deactivate** and it's all. Plugins status don't changes from **Inactive** (grey restangle) to **Active** (green restangle) and nothing more happens. No new widgets or controls appears on admin panel. If I click on **Deactivate** button, then this button label changes to **Activate** and new button **Delete** appears on top right corner, but nothing happens if I click on it.

What happens? Something with directory/file permissions? But all permissions is the same as permissions of working plugins: Application and Colorbox.

Answer (score 0):

when you download plugin from GitHUB, you get unnecessary '-master' suffix. Remove it. Leave just 'FullTinyMCE', 'Favicon', etc.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. If I look for `namespace` in controller.php I don't ask this stupid question.